# How can a server side function in SvelteKit call the OS or another program (eg Python script)?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Using SvelteKit, for some user requests the server needs to make calls to the OS or other programs outside of the space which Sveltekit operates. This can be one of many tasks such as executing a bash script, calling 'ls', or executing a python script. How can this be done in SvelteKit on the server side, eg. `+serever.ts`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [child_process.exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) in Node.js to run arbitrary commands.

```js
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');

exec('"/path/to/test file/test.sh" arg1 arg2');
// Double quotes are used so that the space in the path is not interpreted as
// a delimiter of multiple arguments.

exec('echo "The \\$HOME variable is $HOME"');
// The $HOME variable is escaped in the first instance, but not in the second.
```

And you are right, put your code in a [+server.ts|js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) file, and it will only run on the server when a client request it to run.

```js
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
 
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export function GET({ url }) {

  // Sample code from the docs, but here you can use the child_process module instead.

  const min = Number(url.searchParams.get('min') ?? '0');
  const max = Number(url.searchParams.get('max') ?? '1');
 
  const d = max - min;
 
  if (isNaN(d) || d < 0) {
    throw error(400, 'min and max must be numbers, and min must be less than max');
  }
 
  const random = min + Math.random() * d;
 
  return new Response(String(random));
}
```

Comment: I feel it should be noted that you will have to use [`adapter-node`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node) in your SvelteKit configuration for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Commands can be called within Sveltekit even during development via `import { exec } from 'node:child_process'`

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types'

import { exec } from 'node:child_process'

export const POST:RequestHandler  = async ({request,locals}) => {

    exec('ls ./', (err, stdout,stderr) => {
        console.log({stdout})
    })

    return json({message:"called ls"})
}
```

(+server.ts)